# Sphinxql: several fields matching

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

String with author and his book is given. There are two fields in index: `author` and `title`. I need to find all books where author and title matches.
String may contain only author or only title, so I can't parse it. If I search

```
SELECT id FROM books 
WHERE MATCH('@(author, title) "jane smiley horse heaven");
```

, I don't get the most relevant book with author="jane smiley" and title="horse heaven".

I need something like

```
SELECT id FROM books
WHERE MATCH('@(title) "horse heaven" @(author) "jane smiley"');
```

but without splitting the string.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> MATCH('@(author, title) "jane smiley horse heaven"');

is asking for that exact phrase (quotes are phrase operator). ie those four words sequential in the text. As you say that wont really match.

Instead

```
MATCH('@(author,title) (jane smiley horse heaven)');
```

should mean it just requires those words. But in any field, and technically in any order (so could match against "jane heaven, horse drawn smiley" or whatever ;)

Comment: I guess, there should be no space between `MATCH('@(author,title)')`, e.g. column names

Comment: Well spotted. Yes, there shouldn't be a space there. I guess is possible some versions of sphinx are more forgiving, but current version does not like that space.